# Is Radial Acceleration really Constant?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, magnetic-fields, kinematics, rotational-kinematics

When a charged particle undergoes deflection in a Magnetic Field it follows a curved path while moving with some velocity. We calculate the deflection by finding the radial acceleration and time spent in the field and then put these in the equation s=ut+1/2at². But isn't the radial acceleration changing its direction with the initial point of reference since it is always towards the center? Since it is, then how can we use it to calculate the deflection as if its a straight line motion with constant acceleration?

Comment: Where did you see someone use that formula? It isn't correct here, as you said

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So this means its just an approximation valid for very small arc lengths.

Comment: Does this mean that we can even treat the velocity in the positive x-axis direction to be the same even though the particle deflects in the positive y-axis direction while describing the arc ? I am asking this since the time spent by the particle in the field is calculated by dividing the displacement along the positive x-axis by the velocity at the time of entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concern is real, but possibly negligible...

Yes;  the electron is originally travelling in a straight line. When it hits the perpendicular magnetic field, it begins travelling in a circle.  The radius of the circle is dependent on the velocity of the electron,  the intensity of the magnetic field, the electron charge/mass ratio.

The electron will continue its circular path until it passes beyond the magnetic field (if, indeed, it does.).  It will then continue in a new straight line, tangential to that circle at the point where it leaves the magnetic field.  If the magnetic field covers a large enough area, the electron will complete the circle and repeat its path, losing energy and decreasing it radius.  These spirals can be seen in many cloud chamber or bubble chamber photographs.

However, the use of the word "deflection" in the OP suggests a simplification.  If the area of the magnetic field is small, and the radius of the electron circular path is large, then the direction of the radial force does not have a chance to change very much. (The electron covers only a small part of the arc of a circle). Taking the direction of the radial force as being constant and perpendicular to the original direction of the electron introduces a small error ***and*** simplifies the calculation of the new path.